# How do I use the and operator in XPath?

Tags: html, select, xpath, operator-keyword

I am trying to select all text within ul tags and p tags on a web page. I'm finding it hard to select both at the same time. I can select each separately no problem. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
('//p and ul');
('//p::ul');
```

I'm also trying to select a specific  list. There are multiple lists on the web page but I am only interested in one. How would I go about selecting all  list on a page that are within a  tag with a certain id, e.g.

```
<div id="thisistheid"
<ul....
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I believe you need to use the `//` bit on both sides, like `//p and //ul`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I think you need to use `//p and //ul`, but I'm not certain.

I can certainly answer your second question though: `//div[@id='thisistheid']//ul` will select `ul`s only if they are a descendant of `#thisistheid`. You can also use `/ul` in place of `//ul` to only allow one level of depth (useful if you have nested lists)

Answer (score 1):

[And and Or](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-AndExpr) are boolean expressions:

> An and expression is evaluated by evaluating each operand and converting its value to a boolean as if by a call to the boolean function. The result is true if both values are true and false otherwise. The right operand is not evaluated if the left operand evaluates to false.

Since a node cannot be both P and UL at the same time, your test will never return true.

Try the Union operator (a [PathExpression](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-UnionExpr)) instead:

```
//p | //ul
```

This will give you all the p and ul elements in the document

To get a node with a specific id you can use the [id() function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-id)

```
id('thisistheid')
```

If this doesn't work for whatever reason, you can still use an attribute test, e.g.

```
//div[@id='thisistheid']
```

Or - if you are using the [DOM API](http://www.w3.org/DOM/), you can use `getElementById()`.

You can find an easy to follow XPath tutorial at http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html